# arduino code running on loop

Tags: loops, arduino, switch-statement, arduino-uno

I have used a switch case in my Arduino project and also I have used a for loop on my second case, but the function is not getting out of the for loop. I want to run my second case only for 5sec then wants to break it. Help me with that.

```
int cmd;
void loop(){                     // run over and over again
  if(Serial.available()){
    Serial.println("enter 1 or 2");
    cmd=Serial.read();

    switch (cmd){
      case '1':
        function1() ;
        break ;

      case '2':
        int i=0;
        for(i=0;i<100;i++){
          function2();
          delay(50);
        }
        break;    
    }  
  }    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your loop will always take more then 5 seconds to complete as your total delay is 5 seconds plus the execution time of *function2*. If it is not exiting the loop, my bet would be that your *function2* is responsible for that.
Anyway, if you need timing, you should use the millis() funcion, the result would be something like this:

```
long startTime = millis();
long delay = 50000;

while(millis() < startTime + delay){
    functionw();
}
```

This implementation would be much more closer to your 5 second time limit.

Comment: actually I am using the adafruit fingerprint example files case 1 for enroll and case 2 for fingerprint which can be found on this website ( https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Fingerprint-Sensor-Library/tree/master/examples)

Comment: and wants to run the case 2 till the finger is not placed on the sensor

Comment: Not really sure what you are trying to accomplish, but if you want to do X while something hasn't happened - use Interrupts.